# Teradata Query for extracting data based on time interval (10 minutes

Tags: sql, teradata

Can someone help me with a query in Teradata/SQL that I can use to extract all users that have more than 3 transactions in a timestamp of 10 minutes. Below is an extract of the table in question.

Kind regards,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`/`lead()` and time comparisons.  To get the rows where there are 2 such transactions before:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify transaction_timestamp < lag(transaction_timestamp, -2) over (partition by userid order by transaction_timestamp) + interval '10' minute
```

If you only want the users:

```
select distinct userid
from (select t.*
      from t
      qualify transaction_timestamp < lag(transaction_timestamp, 2) over (partition by userid order by transaction_timestamp) + interval '10' minute
     ) t
```

Comment: negative offset value is not allowed in Lead/Lag Functions. What can i do?

Comment: @CiprianPuiu . . . That was a typo.

Comment: i am still not getting correct values for user IDs, it extracts mostly everything

Comment: @CiprianPuiu . . . The logic was wrong.  You want transactions *within* 10 minutes, which means that the lag from 2 back plus 10 minutes should be less than the transaction time on a given row.

Comment: Much appreciated the help, i managed to extract the data i need.